# Что будет если вернуть значение в рекурсии?

Tags: java, рекурсия

Допустим есть такой метод:

```
public boolean method() {
 ...
 if(check)
   return false;
 ...
 method();
 ...
 return true;
}
```

И допустим у нас есть проверка `if(method)`. Происходит рекурсия, в какой то момент метод вернет `false`. Что будет потом? Что вернет первый вызванный метод? `true` или `false`?

Я просто не помню, после возвращения значения метод идет к завершающим скобкам. И после этого рекурсия прекратится, или все остальные методы будут выходить так сказать из точки с запятой(показано на рисунке) и возвращать `true`, пока в конце последний не вернет `true`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вызванный метод вернет `true`, если в нем дойдет до вызовa `method();`.

---

```
public boolean method() {
 ...
 if(check)
   return false;
 ...
 return method();
}
```

Но в таком случае всегда будет возвращаться `false` - так как это условие остановки рекусии.